# Верно ли понимается значение строки jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #box > *');
```

Из блока с `id="box"`, расположенным по адресу `index.php?route=module/cart` будет вытащено все содержимое, и все это будет загружено в блок с `id="cart"`

Comment: Когда этот метод выполняется, извлекается содержимое index.php?route=module/cart, но затем jQuery разбирает полученный документ и ищет элемент с ID равным box. Этот элемент, со всем своим содержимым, будет вставлен в элемент с ID равным cart и остальная часть загруженного документа будет проигнорирована. [Взято отсюда](https://jquery-docs.ru/load/)